# Can Windows powershell insert into an Oracle database?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, oracle-linux

Through Oracle TNS and/or some sort of ODBC driver, can Windows powershell insert its results into an Oracle database?

In pseudo code"

```
powershell> Get-ComputerInfo -Property "CsNumberOfProcessors"
```

Then

```
Insert into user.MyWindowsBoxes (Processors) Values CsNumberOfProcessors
```

Comment: To answer the question that you asked "Yes".

Comment: You might want to also research calling sqlplus from PS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [root](https://superuser.com/users/254473/root), I found that one can call SP directory with PS, like this:

```
C:\oracle\sqlplus.exe "system/oracle@//myhost:1529/prod" @C:\Users\scripts\powershell\query.sql
```